# How to pass a function into another function in the same module in elixir?

Tags: elixir

In python, we can pass a function into another function like the example code below.

```
def digits(n):
    return list(map(int, str(n)))

def digit_cube(n):
    return list(map(lambda x: x ** 3, digits(n)))
```

Can the same be done in elixir? If yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can pass anonymous functions

```elixir
f = fn e -> e * 2 end
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], f)
```

or capture the existing function with [`&/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1)

```elixir
defmodule M do
  def dbl(e), do: e * 2
  def map_dbl(list) do
    Enum.map(list, &dbl/1)
  end
end
```

Comment: it may be worth mentioning [Kernel.apply/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#apply/3) ?

Comment: @Segfault I think it would be more interesting to point out remote function captures and differences between remote function capture and local function capture.

Comment: @Hauleth but it would be copy-pasting the documentation I have explicitly linked, wouldn’t it?